# PrimeReact: change background color of Menubar items when on hover

Tags: css, reactjs, primereact

i can't change the menu items color when on hover
[image]
As you can see, when on hover the color is shown only in the corners, but not on the actual item.

This is my css code:

```css
/*Menubar*/
.p-menubar {
    background-color: var(--primary) !important;
}
.p-menu-list {
    background-color: var(--primary) !important;
}
.p-menuitem {
    background-color: var(--primary) !important;
}
.p-menu-list:hover {
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
.p-menuitem:hover {
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
.p-menuitem-text, .p-menuitem-icon, .p-submenu-icon {
    color: var(--text-primary) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you need this

```
.p-menuitem-active a {
    background: #000 !important;
}
```

or this depending on whether you want it for `hover` or on expand

```
.p-menuitem-link:hover {
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
```